# CrystalReportViewer Export to Specific Excel Sheet

Tags: vb.net, excel, crystal-reports

The CrystalReportViewer allows me to export my report to an Excel file, but it always saves the report as sheet "Sheet 1" in a new file.

Is there a way to get the CrystalReportViewer to save the report to an existing Excel file and specify what to name the sheet in saves the report to?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Disable CrystalReportViewer export button

```
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer  ....    HasExportButton="false" ... />
```

Add your export toolbar

```
  <asp:Panel ID="exportPanel" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="inLinePanel" >
  <table style="height: 22px; margin-top: 1px; margin-right: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px; margin-left: 1px; display: block; cursor: pointer; " id="CrystalReportViewer1_toptoolbar_addedButtons" class="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"  >
   <tr>
    <td  title="PDF">
     <asp:ImageButton ID="btnPdf" runat="server" OnClick="btnExport_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/PDF.png" CssClass="AddedButton" />
     </td>
    <td title="word">
     <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDoc" runat="server" OnClick="btnExport_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/DOC.png"  />   
     </td>
    <td  title="excel">
     <asp:ImageButton ID="btnXls" runat="server" OnClick="btnExport_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/XLS.png"  />   
     </td>
    <td  title="excel no stile">
     <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCsv" runat="server" OnClick="btnExport_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/CSV.png" />   
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 </asp:Panel>
```

And this is the code-behind

```
 protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ReportDocument reportDocument = CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource ;
    // Stop buffering the response
    Response.Buffer = false;
    // Clear the response content and headers
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    try
    {
        string senderID = ((ImageButton)sender).ID;
        if (senderID == "btnPdf")
            reportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, Page.Title);
        else if (senderID == "btnXls")
            reportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.Excel, Response, true, Page.Title);
        else if (senderID == "btnCsv")
            reportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord, Response, true, Page.Title);
        else if (senderID == "btnDoc")
            reportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.EditableRTF, Response, true, Page.Title);
        // There are other format options available such as Word, Excel, CVS, and HTML in the ExportFormatType Enum given by crystal reports
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Compliance.SmtpHelper.SendErrorMessage("Reportform.Aspx - QueryString: '" + clearQueryString + "' - Dettaglio errore: " + ex.ToString());
        Response.Write(ex.StackTrace);

    }
}
```